# Limit of $f_n(x)=n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What is the limit of $f_n(x)=n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $x>0$?

Thanks for help (tips).

I believe the starting point could be observation that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x$. I think I can also use a fact that if a limit exists and function is continuous, the one can "go with limit inside a function".

Comment: I yesterday accidentally read an old ($\approx 100$ years) Gazette article by Hurwitz where the logarithm is defined by a very similar sequence. It was nicely written, and if you have the possibility to dig it up, I suggest you to read it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

This expression is a variation rate at $0$ of the function $t\longmapsto x^t$, hence its limit is …

Comment: $logx$, but how you come with such conclusion

Comment: That's because the second factor is a difference, so you can rewrite the expression as $$\frac{x^{\tfrac1n}-x^0}{\dfrac1n-0}.$$

Comment: @garyyo You can recognize the expression of a variation rate (whose limit is the derivative) when writing $f_n(x)$ as $\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h-0}$ for $h=1/n$.

Comment: @From Review: Is you comment for me?

Comment: we use a fact that $(a^t)'=a^t \log a$? And at $0$ this derivative is equal to $\log a$.

Comment: @garyyo If it is not clear, you can also rewrite $x^t$ as $e^{t\ln x}$ and apply the usual rules. See my answer: once you have recognized the expression of the derivativate of $g(t) = e^{t\ln x}$ at $t=0$, it boils down to computing it using the usual rules of differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Set $h=\frac{1}{n}\to 0$, and write, for fixed $x_0 > 0$,
$$
f_n(x_0) = \frac{x_0^{h}-1}{h} = \frac{e^{h\ln x_0} - e^0}{h-0}
$$
Does that last form ring a bell?